# setMinHeight and setMaxHeight in android custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I want to set android custom buttons' setMinHeight and setMaxHeight

I have android button widget in the Library project and user of SDK(library project) can take use of that custom Button but I want to put restriction that button's Minimum size has to be **200dp** and button's maximum height can not exceed **350dp** how do i achieve that from custom view Button custom class?

Tried searching lot of thread but not sure yet.

```
public class MyCustomButton extends android.widget.Button {

    public MyCustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        applyDefaults(null);
    }

    public MyCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyDefaults(attrs);
    }

    public MyCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        applyDefaults(attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        applyDefaults(attrs);
    }

    private void applyDefaults(AttributeSet attrs) {

        String height = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height");
        String width = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_width");

        Log.e("MVYAS=======", "height===" + height);
        Log.e("MVYAS=======", "width===" + width);

        setUpButtonForLoginOrLogout();
        setAllCaps(false);
        setMinHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mid_button_min_height));
        setMinWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mid_button_min_width));
        setMaxHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mid_button_max_height));
        setMaxWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mid_button_max_width));

     }

}
```

and while using into layout.xml file

```
 <com.example.library.widget.MyCustomButton
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="153dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        styleButton:mobileid="inverted"/>
```

Here user should not be able to create button height to **57dp** as its lower than the desired button height.

Putting restriction by adding **setMinHeight()** and **setMaxHeight()** dose not work.

How do i achieve that. Your help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these below two methods in `MyCustomButtom` class and try it:

```
@Override
public void setMinimumHeight(int minHeight) {
    super.setMinimumHeight(minHeight);
}

@Override
public void setMinHeight(@Px int minHeight) {
    super.setMinHeight(minHeight);
}
```

And one more thing, add below line in **`applyDefaults()`** function.

```
setMinimumHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mid_button_min_height));
```